# Aptitude error with linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt, aptitude

I think my problem is very common, but I didn't fix the solution...

When I try to use apt (on Ubuntu 16.04 Server), I get this error :

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  crda iw wireless-regdb
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 167 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 105682 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic (4.13.0-45.50~16.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-45-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-45-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-45-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-45-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Same error when running `apt-get install -f`...

Have someone an idea ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

My server is an OpenVZ virtual machine, so kernel updates are managed by the host (explanations [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853877/ubuntu-14-04-in-an-openvz-container-apt-trying-to-upgrade-the-kernel) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855755/force-removal-of-unwanted-linux-image-extra-packages/859901#859901)).

I had to remove manually `linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic` and `linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic`, by following the post #3 on [this topic](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264110).